# NetBeans 8.0 Gradle Plug-in (for LibGDX)

Tags: java, netbeans, libgdx

I wanted to start using LibGDX but since they switcher to gradle recently I folowed their guides.
According to those,I installed the plugin Gradle support on NetBeans 8.0 and when I try to open a Gradle Project 
I get the error:
Failed to load Gradle Project:test

and when i go to the stacktrace, i get this

```
Issue 1


  Requested project: C:\Users\Halo\Downloads\test

  Stack trace:
    org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.model.GenericModelFetcher.getModels(GenericModelFetcher.java:166)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.NbGradle18ModelLoader$ProjectModelFetcher.getModels(NbGradle18ModelLoader.java:374)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.NbGradle18ModelLoader.loadModels(NbGradle18ModelLoader.java:79)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.GradleModelLoader.loadModelWithProgress(GradleModelLoader.java:496)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.GradleModelLoader.access$600(GradleModelLoader.java:57)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.GradleModelLoader$6.run(GradleModelLoader.java:364)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.runNonBlockingGradleTask(GradleDaemonManager.java:24)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.access$100(GradleDaemonManager.java:14)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager$2.run(GradleDaemonManager.java:105)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager$3.run(GradleDaemonManager.java:130)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1423)
        at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
    This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
    For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
    Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
    Please read below process output to find out more:
    -----------------------

        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:90)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:95)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:149)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:74)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:106)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:100)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:143)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ActionAwareConsumerConnection.run(ActionAwareConsumerConnection.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:82)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

In the code it says that it's caused by Daemon, can someone explain to me how to fix it? it's really torturing my head and I'm about to give the finger to LibGDX and smash my pc into smitherings.
I'll add that I've tried to use the gradlew inside the folder of the project that LibGDX has built (using cmd) but i've got no clue to what to do and, apart for the Gradle support plug-in i've got nothing else about gradle on my pc

Comment: You can still use LibGDX without gradle (download 0.9.9 and use the old setup-tool to create standard projects, which are not based on gradle). You can also use another IDE, since I assume it's a Netbeans gradle-plugin problem here, no libgdx specific one.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the same error on Eclipse too

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, turned out to be a proxy problem. Gradle does not see your proxy setting and you have to add them manually to the gradle.properties file in the project.

It then donwloads all relevant jar files when you build the project.

Used this page setup : http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html